# ggplot2 gets the density wrong?

Tags: r, graphics, ggplot2

Here is the code:

```
dat = data.frame(method=gl(3, 100), res=c(rnorm(100), rnorm(100, 1, 1), rnorm(100, 2, 1)))
png('/tmp/a.png')
p = ggplot(dat)
p = p + stat_density(aes(x=res, group=method, color=as.factor(method)), geom='line')
print(p)
dev.off()

png('/tmp/b.png')
res1 = dat[dat$method==1, ]
res2 = dat[dat$method==2, ]
res3 = dat[dat$method==3, ]
plot(density(res1))
lines(density(res2$res), col='green')
lines(density(res3$res), col='red')
dev.off()
```

Results:

[image]
[image]

One can see the second figure using `plot()` is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the `stat_density()` default position is `"stack"` - so those three lines are stacked. To get the same result as in `plot()` use `position="identity"`.

```
ggplot(dat)+ stat_density(aes(x=res, group=method, color=as.factor(method)), 
         geom='line',position="identity")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Why not use geom_density?

```
  ggplot(dat) + 
  geom_density(aes(x=res, color=as.factor(method)))
```